# Call @BeforeStep in Spring batch Configuration Class to add entry in StepExecution ExecutionContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to add entry in the Step Execution Context, the value i'm tring to add provide from paramters and i want to use it in the processor and the writer.
Is there any way to do pass the value of fileName to my processor and my writer?

Help please

Thank you

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.file.name}")
    private String fileName;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<IApp> reader() {
        // I need to pass fileName to processor and writer
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<IApp>().resource(new ClassPathResource(fileName)).lineMapper(lineMapper())
                .saveState(false).build();
    }

    // Other methods

    @Bean
    public Job processAppJob(Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processAppJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(AppWriter writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<IApp, List<CarteApp>>chunk(10).listener(new AppReadListener())
                .reader(reader()).processor(new AppProcessor()).writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AppWriter writer() {
        return new AppWriter();
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void initializeValues(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        //Never Called
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("FILE_NAME", fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `initializeValues` annotated with `@BeforeStep` is not part of any step of your job. You declared it in the configuration class `BatchConfiguration` which is incorrect.

You need to add this method in one of the step components, like for example in the writer:

```
public class SavingItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
        // ...

        ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("someKey", someObject);
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
}
```

You can find more details in the [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) section of the reference documentation.

> Is there any way to do pass the value of fileName to my processor and my writer?

You can declare your processor or writer as a step scoped bean and inject the job parameter in it. Here is an example for an item processor:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor<Object, Object > itemProcessor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<Object, Object>() {

        @Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")
        private String fileName;

        @Override
        public Object process(Object item) {
            // use parameter fileName as required
            return item;
        }
    };
}
```

This approach does not require using the step execution context.

Answer (score -1):

You can externalize your reader in a class extending `FlatFileItemReader` :

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class YourFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<CarteApp> {

    public YourFlatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['FILE_NAME']}") String fileName) {
        this.setResource(new ClassPathResource(fileName));
        this.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        this.setSaveState(false);
    }
}
```

Then in your `BatchConfiguration` you can inject your reader :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.file.name}")
    private String fileName;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public YourFlatFileItemReader yourFlatFileItemReader;

    // Other methods

    @Bean
    public Job processAppJob(Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processAppJob")
                  .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                  .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                      jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("FILE_NAME", fileName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

                    }
                   })
                  .flow(step1).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(AppWriter writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<IApp, List<CarteApp>>chunk(10)
                .reader(yourFlatFileItemReader).processor(new AppProcessor()).writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AppWriter writer() {
        return new AppWriter();
    }

}
```

I think there are others solutions but I don't know how.